# Conditional breakpoint triggers when it should not

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, java-native-interface, native

I am investigating an exception that crashes the JVM, due to an error happening in native code. To do so I attach VS to the *javaw*  process and debug functions that are relevant to my problem.

The function I am currently looking at looks as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_bytedeco_javacpp_BoolPointer_allocateArray(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jlong arg0) {
    bool* rptr = new (std::nothrow) bool[arg0];
    jlong rcapacity = arg0;
    JavaCPP_initPointer(env, obj, rptr, rcapacity, rptr, &JavaCPP_org_bytedeco_javacpp_BoolPointer_deallocateArray);
}
```

This is JNI generated code to enable communication between Java and native code.

Since I suspect a certain condition to trigger unhandled exceptions that eventually cause the JVM to hard-crash, a breakpoint is used, to investigate the function shown above.

The breakpoint is conditional and holds the following condition:

```
"arg0 < 1" is "True"
```

It must trigger on values of one or negative values **only**. Apparently I am setting this up incorrectly, because the breakpoint triggers repeatedly on `arg0` values, such as `3178311`.

First I thought of an overflow with VS incorrectly converting the value in the *Local* window, where the variables are displayed on debug. However there were values as low as `8900` which makes this idea unlikely.

Also in the past I have noticed, that sometimes values do not refresh immediately, so I am always stepping through the function, when a breakpoint triggers, however the values remain consistently larger than 0.

What am I doing incorrectly? Why is my breakpoint triggering? Does VS resolve `arg0` properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the breakpoint on the first line of your code, the values of the parameters are not yet initialized in VS (this also happens if you step into functions manually). Put the breakpoint on the second line (anywhere after the opening brace) and it might work.

Comment: Thank you. So the issue is with placing the breaking at the line of method signature. As I understand this, at that moment VS does not know of arg0? In any case, this helped.

Comment: @Mär If you look at the disassembly, you will frequently find that some parameters are pushed from the registers to the stack. This happens "between" the opening brace and the first line of the function. The debugging information from the compiler presumably only tells the debugger about these stack locations for the values (and the debugger doesn't know this is wrong before the first line is reached). The debug information could also track this, but that would be useless for most purposes and just bloat it.